# How to parse serialized json from php web service in java play framework 1.2.x

Tags: java, json, playframework, jsonserializer

I need to use some from from a `php web service` which `rendering its data` by `serializing json` in `java play framework 1.2.x`. What i am doing just using `play WS` function. and i am getting data from that service. But when I try to get it with `JSONObject` it throws excepiton which is so normal, because the returned data does not look a `json format` well. Any body who knows any workarounds or solution would be appreciated.

```
HttpResponse htp = WS.url("http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=78.171.90.49").get();            
System.out.println(htp.getContentType()+"\n"+htp.getStatusText()+"\n"+htp.getString());
```

The returned data :

```
a:18:{s:17:"geoplugin_request";s:12:"78.171.90.49";s:16:"geoplugin_status";i:200;s:16:"geoplugin_credit";s:145:"Some of the returned data includes GeoLite data created by MaxMind, available from <a href=\'http://www.maxmind.com\'>http://www.maxmind.com</a>.";s:14:"geoplugin_city";s:8:"Istanbul";s:16:"geoplugin_region";s:8:"Istanbul";s:18:"geoplugin_areaCode";s:1:"0";s:17:"geoplugin_dmaCode";s:1:"0";s:21:"geoplugin_countryCode";s:2:"TR";s:21:"geoplugin_countryName";s:6:"Turkey";s:23:"geoplugin_continentCode";s:2:"EU";s:18:"geoplugin_latitude";s:7:"41.0186";s:19:"geoplugin_longitude";s:9:"28.964701";s:20:"geoplugin_regionCode";s:2:"34";s:20:"geoplugin_regionName";s:8:"Istanbul";s:22:"geoplugin_currencyCode";s:3:"TRY";s:24:"geoplugin_currencySymbol";s:15:"&#89;&#84;&#76;";s:29:"geoplugin_currencySymbol_UTF8";s:3:"YTL";s:27:"geoplugin_currencyConverter";s:6:"2.2669";}
```

Comment: It sounds like you are accessing geoplugin, but getting back a JavaScript output instead of a pure JSON one. Can you elaborate on what service/url you are accessing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the PHP endpoint. You need to hit this URL instead:

http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=78.171.90.49